# selecting first n elements of a set

Tags: python

i have a large `set` of elements to iterate over. for debugging purposes, i'd only like to iterate over the first, say, ~10. To achieve this, i've created a `list` initialised from my `set`, selected the first 10 elements via `[:10]`, and iterated over the resulting `list`. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
mySet = set(df.SomeUniqueId)
myList = list(mySet)[:10]
for i, val in enumerate(myList):
    ...
```

Comment: can you just cast it as a list? `for i, val in enumerate(list(df.SomeUniqueId)[:10]):
    ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "*first*"? Sets have no order, there is no "first" 10.

Comment: @Robᵩ ok fair enough, i'm new to sets and didn't really consider the fact that they have no order. i guess i was thinking of the set in terms of a sorted list, and was referring to the first 10 elements of that "list."

Comment: `s/first/arbitrary/` :-)

Comment: `myList = [el for (el, _) in zip(mySet, range(10))]` seems to do the trick, without converting the entire set into a list, and without requiring extra imports.
Tested in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). Generating that whole list, just to access the first few items, seems wasteful to me.

```
for i, val in enumerate(itertools.islice(mySet, 10)):
```

EDIT:

If you want to *randomly* choose (in contrast to *arbitrarily* choose) your ten elements, try [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
for i, val in enumerate(random.sample(mySet, 10)):
```

Comment: Note that while `islice()` works happily when there's fewer elements than requested in the set (eg: <10), `random.sample()` will throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. Using list(set(a)) will create a list, which can take a long time depending on your set. But, since you only need to iterate for a small number of loops, I would use an iterator and a counter:

```
count = 0
for elem in iter(mySet):
    count = count + 1
    if count == 10:
        break
    print elem
```

This would avoid the overhead of creating a long list, and the overhead of having some manual code to control the loop is likely to be negligible.

Comment: It can't *possibly* be Pythonic if it takes more than one line :-)

Comment: True. Rob's answer is better than mine :)

Comment: this did occur to the inner C++ programmer in me, but as @paxdiablo stated it doesn't feel particularly pythonic (I'm slowly trying to convert my thinking from C+ to python!).